# Loud clattering from engine upon start-up (sometimes)

Tags: engine, ford

1990 Ford E150 5.0. Has been a sweet runner for the 15 yrs I've owned it. I use it as a camper and sometimes antique hauler so it sits alot with the battery disconnected (slight drain that I have not chased down). Last week I had a mechanic friend listen with the hood up to try to locate a cold-run belt squeal and when I started the engine it clattered very loudly, so I shut it right down. Friend checked for loose parts, didn't find anything, so I restarted and all was okay again. The noise was extremely loud and sounded like rods knocking with a dollop of  loose bolts left over in the combustion chambers. (I am familiar with both sounds having been a certified mechanic back in the Seventies.) I then took it home and it sat for a few days, with battery connected. Next start-up it clattered again, thru many starts and shut-downs. I let it sit a day and it started up fine.
My experience tells me it's severe pre-ignition because the clattering occurrences are always preceded by the sound of bad timing when cranking. There cannot be a sensor that is telling the ECU to send out such a bizarre timing message so it must be the ECU itself. No CEL. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your description to me sounds like the oil is draining out of the lifters and galleys over time and you get a clatter of a worn engine on start up. As soon as oil pressure comes up, it sounds fine. This could be due to a bad anti-drainback valve an oil filter.

Comment: Looks good enough to be the answer. I was going to suggest the same. I remember it being a pretty common issue in 70 and 80's Fords. If the vehicle sits for extended periods (weeks or months). Before restarting, I would pull the fuel pump fuse, crank it long enough to build oil pressure. Then reinstall the fuse and start the engine. This will limit the time the engine is running with what is essentially misadjusted lifters.

Comment: @mikes - The reason I didn't post it as an answer is, I don't have a "fix" for it. I don't know if it would just require lifters, a new oil pump, or a complete rebuild.

Comment: @Mikes, thanks for the thoughts. Clattering does not happen every time nor after a long sit. Happened twice over a week period being started  multiple times. Started quiet the last three days. Two points I want to repeat: the noise when it happens is scary/horrible/loud; and, I am positive it is not a mechanical cause. My question then becomes - which sensor(s) can send a bogus signal to the EECM that might cause a screwy ignition timing command? If it's not a sensor, that leaves me with the computer (which IMO is such a amateur part-swapper answer but I may be stuck with it).